What is the physical meaning lying behind Zernike polynomials?
I was simply told that Zernike polynomials are mutually othogonal and are useful in optics , but I cannot see how do they relates to defocus, aberrations, etc. Moreover, I am also wondering they are solutions to an equation, but I didn't find it.

The book by Born and Wolf may help.

I am also wondering they are solutions to an equation, but I didn't find it. Wikipedia has a second-order differential equation that they satisfy.

Very generally, the Zernike polynomials relate to optical aberrations in the following way: the optical system is relaying an optical wavefront from one point (the object) to another (the image).
In a typical optical system, the wavefront is ought to be spherical (or planar in case of collimated light, but let's discard that for the moment).
Any deviation from a spherical wavefront (which is also called a wavefront error) will correspond with an optical aberration, which will result in a blur to some extent.
One may decompose any arbitrary wavefront error into a linear combination of Zernike polynomials (much like how one may decompose a continuous smooth curve into a linear combination of sine waves, i.e. Fourier decomposition).

Zernike polynomials are mathematical functions useful for describing wavefront aberrations on the intermediate pupil.

To answer your second question:
Orthogonal polynomials are solutions to certain Sturm-Liouville problems. That is they satisfy some partiall differential equation. The Zernike polynomials $V^m_n(x,y)$, where $m=2n-j$ and $j=0,1,...,n$, are disk polynomials so they can be defined as complex polynomials. They can be used to find polynomials minimizing the  $L^2$-norm $\lVert f-p \rVert_2$, where $f$ is a function on the unit-disk. The underlying premise is that errors in circular optical elements can be quantified by mean-square deviation per unit area. They satisfy the differential equation
$$ \left(4\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z \partial\overline{z}}-\left(z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}+\overline{z}\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}\right)^2-2(\alpha+1)\left(z \frac{\partial}{\partial z}+\overline{z}\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}\right)\right)V^m_n(z,\overline{z})=-n(n+2+2\alpha)V^m_n(z,\overline{z})$$
where $\alpha>-1$.
Taken from
M. Born, E. Wolf, "Principles of optics" , Pergamon (1965) (Edition: Third)
A. Klimyk, N. Vilenkin, "Representations of Lie groups and special functions" , Kluwer Acad. Publ. (1993)
T. Koornwinder, "Two-variable analogues of the classical orthogonal polynomials" R. Askey (ed.) , Theory and Applications of Special Functions , Acad. Press (1975) pp. 435–495
R. Marr, "On the reconstruction of a function on a circular domain from a sampling of its line integrals" J. Math. Anal. Appl. , 45 (1974) pp. 357–374
F. Zernike, "Beugungstheorie des Schneidensverfahrens und seiner verbesserten Form, der Phasenkontrastmethode" Physica , 1 (1934) pp. 689–704
F. Zernike, H. Brinkman, "Hypersphärische Funktionen und die in sphärischen Bereichen orthogonalen Polynome" Proc. K. Akad. Wetensch. , 38 (1935) pp. 161–170

How does this answer the question regarding defocus and aberrations?

@Semoi I highlighted which part of the question this answer is referring to

Your differential equation for $V_n^m$ doesn’t contain $m$, and you don’t explain how $\alpha$ might be related to $m$ and $n$.

Two answer your second question You mean “To answer…”.

@Ghoster $\alpha$ is related neither to $m$ nor to $n$. It is just a parameter and $m$ is expressed trough $n$
